# java.lang.NumberFormatException while formatting a String

Tags: android

I'm getting NumberFormatException: For input string: "4045989016914" while trying to format the string as the following

```
String.format("%013d", Integer.valueOf(itemMODEL.getCodiceArticolo()))
```

itemMODEL.getCodiceArticolo is a String that would be a barcode and i would to add 0 if it's shorted than 13 so the code i'm using should be right but i can't get why i'm getting that error.

> 2018-10-08 16:01:37.420 12670-12670/it.gabtamagnini.realco
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: it.gabtamagnini.realco, PID: 12670
>       java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4045989016914"
>           at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:524)
>           at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:611)
>           at it.gabtamagnini.realco.InventarioActivity.Tracciato(InventarioActivity.java:471)
>           at it.gabtamagnini.realco.InventarioActivity$9.onClick(InventarioActivity.java:429)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22433)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6130)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Comment: Show the whole stacktrace.

Comment: @TheWanderer added

Comment: Well, it's too big for an integer (4-byte, signed). Use Long instead

Comment: @Christopher damn you're right didn't noticed it, now that's working fine thank's for help

Comment: You also shouldn't even need `Integer.valueOf()`. Just use `%s` and pass the String as an argument to the formatter directly.

Comment: @Christopher write it as an answer as you're the 1st one who gave it

Comment: @TheWanderer that's a nice one too thank's for suggestion's guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your barcode is too big to fit into a 4-byte Integer. The max. positive range of an Integer is `2^31 - 1 = 2147483647`. You should use `Long` instead:

```
String.format("%013d", Long.valueOf(itemMODEL.getCodiceArticolo()))
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Christopher's answer, you shouldn't even need to convert it to a Number.

You should be able to simply do:

```
String code = itemMODEL.getCodiceArticolo());
```

No point in converting to a Number only for it to be made back into a String. You don't need a format either this way.